# Получить кол-во записей из таблицы SQLite в Lazarus

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, lazarus, dbgrid

В процессе создания приложения возникла огромная куча вопросов по работе с БД в Lazarus. Вот несколько наиболее актуальных для меня вопросов по этой теме:

**1.** *Необходимо получить информацию о кол-ве записей в таблице* и поместить эту инфу хотя бы в Label, в моей программе за неимением в стандартной сетке футера я использую StatusBar. Для этого нацарапал вот такую запись:

```
count:=MainForm.SQLQuery5.Fields[0].AsString;
MainForm.StatusBar1.Panels.Items[5].Text:=count;
```

, где **count:string;**
Информация получается не достоверная как только я начинаю совершать какие-либо действия с записями, в частности произвольное удаление записей. Покажу на скринах. Так выглядит таблица БД SQLite до совершения изменений:

[image: Так выглядит таблица БД SQLite до совершения изменений:]

Тут есть поле RecNo, которое создала сама программа с помощью которой я сотворял базу(SQLite Expert) - его не видно в датасете и данные с него взять не получается и поле которое я сам создал(RecNum) - уникальное автоинкрементное. До удаления записей, номера строк в этих двух полях идентичны. Затем удаляю несколько строк произвольно и получаю результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно номера строк уже не совпадают, а именно номера в моем поле имеют пропуски, номера удаленных строк не переприсвоились другим строчкам как это произошло с первым полем...а мой код дает инфу именно по полю RecNum, соответственно он говорит что записей 9, но как видно их на самом деле 7... Внимание  :!: вопрос :?: либо нужно переделать код запроса кол-ва записей(я понятия не имею как это сделать ибо перепробовал кучу вариантов) либо сделать каким то образом поле такое же как и поле созданное программой SQLite Expert.... :|

**2.** *В стандартной DBGrid я не нашел футер. Можно ли его каким либо образом создать* :?:  :!:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью подсказки более опытных программистов, пришел к такому решению:
Создаем отдельный SQLQuery, внутри компонента, в параметре SQL пишем такой код

```
SELECT Count (*) as RecNum From MainTable
```

,т.е. получаем кол-во записей по полю RecNum из таблицы MainTable.
Дальше в программе, в событиях на создание новых записей или на удаление записей, пишется вот такой код

```
StatusBar1.Panels.Items[5].Text:='Всего записей: ' +' '+SQLQuery5.FieldByName('RecNum').AsString;
```

Соответственно в статус бар, в панели 5 будет размещено кол-во записей в базе.

По поводу второго моего вопроса, следующее: в стандартной сетке я Footer не нашел, его вроде как то можно создать, но для новичка сложно. Поэтому я использовал бесплатную библиотеку RxLib, а точнее сетку оттуда - RxDBGrid. В ней есть достаточно интересные опции, в т.ч. footer. Записал в него кол-во записей в базе:

```
 RxDBGrid1.ColumnByFieldName('Otdel').Footer.Value:=SQLQuery5.FieldByName('RecNum').AsString;
```

Футер рисуется не целым полем, а деленным на маленькие поля, в соответствии с полями базы, которые я включил для отображения в сетке. В данном случае в футере в поле соответствующем полю Otdel я буду хранить данные о кол-ве записей.

Может кому пригодится =) Тяжело в учении...